# CentOS and /dev/midi support

Tags: linux, centos

I recently [asked earlier](https://superuser.com/questions/2879/connecting-a-midi-controller-to-centos5) about connecting a MIDI controller to CentOS. I've got the same problem, except now I'm backtracing to find a different way at it. I'm talking about the elusive `/dev/midi` file mentioned in many tutorials. Has anyone managed to install/set up said device in Linux? On my box, neither /dev/midi, nor /dev/sequencer exist,

(oh, and by the way- could someone please tag this "midi"? I don't have enough rep to do so...)

Answer (score 2):

Cricket. I eventually tried it on an Debian system and it worked perfectly.

Solution: don't use CentOS.

Comment: Debian has many, many more packages than the RPM-based distros. If it works with linux, it'll likely work with Debian.